# How do you find the Fourier transform of a function?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

I will illustrate this with a simple example:

> Consider the exponential decay function $$f(t)=\begin{cases}
>  0  &
>  \ t\lt 0 , \\ A e^{-\lambda t} & \ t\ge 0 \end{cases}$$
>   Where $\lambda \gt 0$ and $A$ is a constant.

Using the formula for the Fourier transform of $f(t)$: 
$$\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{0}0e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=0}^{\infty}\color{#F80}{e^{-\left(\lambda+i\omega \right)t}\mathrm{d}t}$$ 
                                                                                                                                $$=0 + \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{e^{-\left(\lambda+i\omega  \right)t}}{\lambda + i \omega}\right]_{t=0}^{\infty}=\color{#180}{\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\lambda+i\omega )}}$$

My question is how was this integration carried out? Since the $\color{#F80}{\mathrm{integrand}}$ is a function of 2 variables ($\omega$ **and** $t$).

Thank you kindly.

Comment: your orange integrand is wrong, before anything else

Comment: @grdgfgr well spotted, better now?

Comment: There should be no $f(t)$ in orange.

Comment: @mickep why is that, it's part of the integrand right?

Comment: You have already inserted the expression for $f$.

Comment: @mickep thanks, removed it

Comment: @mickep Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You integrate with respect to $t$ so $\omega$ is considered as a constant here.

Comment: Please justify _why_ $\omega$ is considered constant?

Comment: Why? Because you integrate with respect to $t$. Also, $\lambda$ is a constant.

Comment: Please justify _why_ $\omega$ is considered constant. $\omega$ is a function of $t$, I know that $\lambda$ is a constant.

Comment: No, $\omega$ is _not_ a function of $t$.

Comment: but it is a variable, right?

Comment: It is the variable used for the transformed function. But in your integral, you integrate with respect to $t$, and therefore $\omega$ is seen as a constant.

Comment: okay, acknowledged

Comment: @BLAZE if still cannot understand, you can always try the simplest case to help you. Just let $f(x,y)=x+y$, and then calculate $\int f(x,y)\; dx$.

Comment: @Stan Thanks for your response. So that's like 'partial integration' right?

Comment: @BLAZE technically, yes.